# Testing Behat Scripts in Googlechrome

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, behat

I am trying to run my scripts using Google chrome ..

In behat.yml

```
default:
    extensions:
            Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:
            base_url: http://downingtown.calendar.comcast.net/prefs
            javascript_session: selenium
            browser_name: googlechrome
            goutte: ~
            selenium: ~
```

I am running the selenium like

```
 java -jar selenium.jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=D:\mypgms\NewMng\chrome\chromeDriver.exe
```

But i am getting SSL certificate Error . Then I could not able to proceed further .

```
1.Am i missing anything ? 
2.Can i disable SSL certificate ?
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In behat.yml

```
default:
  extensions:
    Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:
      base_url: http://downingtown.calendar.comcast.net/prefs
      javascript_session: selenium2
      selenium2: 
        browser: chrome
      goutte: ~
```

For more information, look at Extension.php